# Why are there no hats for Ask Ubuntu meta?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Why can't I wear a hat on my Ask Ubuntu Meta Account?

Comment: Meta hates hats.

Comment: Meta is serious business, and you do not joke about serious things. Hats are a joke.

Comment: Meta needs hats. Its so drab and gray around here.

Comment: @Alvar Meta *is not* ***only*** for things that are serious. Actually, if any goofing off happens on any site, it would be in meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because hats eat babies, and Meta is where the baby Ask Ubuntu's are born and raised.

Just for your sake however, I have retained a picture of a hatted Moderator, for your research. Do not attempt to find this creature as it will eat all of the babies in Meta and Ask Ubuntu will die.

> [image]

**Tip:** Mouse over the quote. But keep your seat belt on.

Comment: GAH! [redacted] has gone to the dark side!

Comment: No giveaways :D